# Refetch firestore data on page reload

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I want to refetch firebase firestore data each time I enter a page. Currently it only works when I reload the page with Ctrl+R or somethting, but not when I route to this page with a routerLink. I hope it's understandable what I mean :)

I tried destroying the data with ngOnDestroy and things to make it async as possible. I also looked for solutions on the web, but nothing worked for me.

**In Component** where I want to show the data:

```
data: Data[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadService.getData().subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
    });
  }
```

**In Service** where I load the data:

```
  dataCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Data>;
  dataDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Data>;
  data: Observable<Data[]>;

  constructor(private afStore: AngularFirestore, private afStorage: 
  AngularFireStorage, private notification: NotificationService) {
    this.dataCollection = afStore.collection('data');
    this.data = this.dataCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Data;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }
```

So this works for the way when I reload the page manually, but not with internal navigations of the Angular Router.

Comment: Service gets instantiated only once and hence constructor is called for the first time. Move your snapshot changes code to `getData()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The internal update on navigation has to do with the angular change detection. In this case you have to trigger the change detection by your self, like in this example form my git:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CalcComponent } from '../calc-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-circular-area',
  templateUrl: './circular-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circular-area.component.scss']
})
export class CircularAreaComponent implements OnInit {
  public render: Boolean;
  public radius: number;
  public r: number;
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  onChange(event: any, r: number) {
    console.log(r);
    this.r = Number(r);
    this.render = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.render = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.render = false;
  }
}
```

Use the call

```
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

to update your components.

and a flag that you trigger it once !